# Windows 7 shows Blue Screen on a regular basis

Tags: windows, bsod

My Windows 7 64 bit crashed and I reinstalled it. It's giving me a blue screen on a regular basis.

After the clean installation I ghosted back my applications. Now, every application is incompatible with my OS-

McAfee Antivirus says everything is ok. `CHKDSK` says "73 Reparse records Processed".

Comment: It was giving you blue screens before you reinstalled? Or it was giving you blue screens after you reinstalled? Since you didn't actually ask a question, it's hard to figure out what you need help with. Is your issue blue screens or applications not working? Also, what makes you think your applications are incompatible with your OS?

Answer (score 2):

When you ghosted back, you would have overwritten the Windows 7 reinstall and put your system back to how it was before... You should have been able to ghost without any operating system in the first place.

If your system worked fine before the ghost, I think the problem could be an incompatible driver or software based issue. You can't rule out bad hardware, but, it can be hard to diagnose and I would need more information - for starters, download and run this - [Blue Screen View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html).

If it crashed straight after the reinstall, it could identify some sort of hardware failure.

To help further, we really need more information.

Comment: If it keeps bluescreening too much to do diagnostics on the system itself, you can copy out c:/minidump to another system and just drag it into blue screen view. Pretty neat trick i discovered by accident

Comment: +1 Awesome - had no idea! This may come in handy - thanks.